# Golang curve25519 pubkey generator

Tags: python, go, cryptography, golang-migrate

I'm trying to implement the curve25519 algo for pubkey generation. But I got stuck on how to generate pubkey from sha256 encoded string in Go?

I have no problems with generation pubkey from sha256 encoded string via Python:

```py
import hashlib
import x25519

example_string = 'kerielle'

sha = hashlib.sha256(example_string.encode()).hexdigest()
hash_bytes = bytes.fromhex(sha)
public_key = x25519.scalar_base_mult(hash_bytes)
hex_res = public_key.hex()

print(hex_res)
>>> 0fa065fcaedecef9aebb5c79ea1c613e82bc5534c4b139d71f3a1cb0cb956652
```

But how to do the same in Go? Here basic example:

```golang
var publicKey [32]byte
privateKey := (*[32]byte)(bytes.Repeat([]byte("1"), 32))
curve25519.ScalarBaseMult(&publicKey, privateKey)

fmt.Printf("%x\n", publicKey)
>>> 04f5f29162c31a8defa18e6e742224ee806fc1718a278be859ba5620402b8f3a
```

Comment: It's not really your question, but you could just write `hash_bytes = hashlib.sha256(....).digest()`.  Calling `digest()` gives you the result as a byte string.

Comment: Why do you think your code doesn't work?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply. No, I do not think that my code does not work. I just want to get correct golang algo which generates from example string `kerielle` following pubkey `0fa065fcaedecef9aebb5c79ea1c613e82bc5534c4b139d71f3a1cb0cb956652`

Comment: Sorry.  I don't know golang.  I only know that Python gives the same result when you call `x25519.scalar_base_mult(b'1' * 32).hex()`.   I looked at https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/sha256 and it has a function for sha256() and some sample code.

Comment: Thanks Frank Yellin. It works for me!

Answer (score 3):

This simply replicates the result of the Python code sample while also taking into account guidance from [the `curve25519.ScalarBaseMult()` documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519#ScalarBaseMult):

> It is recommended to use the X25519 function with Basepoint instead,
> as copying into fixed size arrays can lead to unexpected bugs.

```golang
package main

import (
    "crypto/sha256"
    "fmt"
    "log"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/curve25519"
)

func main() {
    example_string := "kerielle"
    hash := sha256.Sum256([]byte(example_string))
    publicKey, err := curve25519.X25519(hash[:], curve25519.Basepoint)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("curve25519.X25519() failed: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%x\n", publicKey)
}
```

Output:

```
0fa065fcaedecef9aebb5c79ea1c613e82bc5534c4b139d71f3a1cb0cb956652
```

[Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/SJJN7w1ob8I)

Comment: Thanks chuckx for advanced solution. This is what I tried to find for some time.